# How to clean the 20newsgroup dataset for nlp tasks

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to practice a classification task on NLP. I am using [20newsgroup](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html) dataset and I want to implement a classification model. Before training model, I want to implement:

1. stopword removal
2. punctuation removal
3. converting to lower case - since it's not Sentiment analysis task, so case distinction doesn't matter here according to me.

I am using the following code:

```
max_len = 0
for sent in x_train:

    tokenizer_out = tokenizer(sent)
    # convert numerical tokens to alphabetical tokens
    encoded_tok = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer_out.input_ids)
    tokens_without_sw = [word for word in encoded_tok if not word in stopwords.words()]
    new_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens_without_sw)
    max_len = max(max_len, len(new_ids))
```

I will be using pretrained BERT from hugging face. And before implementing the code above, I had done the following to remove unnecessary lines:

```
def clean(post: str, remove_it: tuple):
  new_lines = []
  for line in post.splitlines():
        if not line.startswith(remove_it):
            new_lines.append(line)
  return '\n'.join(new_lines)

remove_it = (
      'From:',
      'Subject:',
      'Reply-To:',
      'In-Reply-To:',
      'Nntp-Posting-Host:',
      'Organization:',
      'X-Mailer:',
      'In article <',
      'Lines:',
      'NNTP-Posting-Host:',
      'Summary:',
      'Article-I.D.:'
  )
x_train = [clean(p, remove_it) for p in x_train]
x_test = [clean(p, remove_it) for p in x_test]
```

My next goal is to clean it further. With my classification, I am able to achieve  90% accuracy but I want to increase it further. SO, I want to remove the stopwords and punctuations, convert to lower case and see what happens. But with the code I use, its taking like forever to run, so I want a faster approach.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You'll also want to implement some sort of quote removal; many messages in the corpus are dominated by quoted text from previous messages in the same thread.

Comment: Your header removal logic is flawed. Junk everything up through the first empty line.